# Appium recorded code not working when launched via nodes

Tags: webdriver, appium

I have successfully installed and run appium desktop. I took to recording my test. The recorder's output code was as follows:

```
// Requires the webdriverio client library
// (npm install webdriverio)
// Then paste this into a .js file and run with Node:
// node <file>.js

const wdio = require('webdriverio');
const caps = {"platformName":"android","platformVersion":"8.0","deviceName":"Nexus_6_API_26_2","automationName":"UiAutomator2","app":"path/to/my/apk"};
const driver = wdio.remote({
  protocol: "http",
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 4723,
  path: "/wd/hub",
  desiredCapabilities: caps
});

driver.init()
  .element("/some/xpath")
  .setValue("Hello World!")
  .end();
```

However this setup after running with `node this_test.js` will find error

`Error: Required option "capabilities" is missing`

Therefore I changed `desiredCapabilities: caps` to `capabilities: caps`, but after that I get error

`TypeError: driver.init is not a function`

What can I change to fix this? I have tried reinstalling `webdriverio` with both `npm install -g webdriverio` and `yarn add webdriverio`.

My server is running on `127.0.0.1:4723` with message "The URL '/' did not map to a valid resource" (if that is relevant)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using MAC or Windows machine ? The address for MAC would be different, something like 0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. Turns out that the `/wd/hub` part is actually unrelated. I am still having problems with `driver.init is not a function`, with a similar error being thrown for any function. I think that `driver` is just yet undefined, but I have no idea how to declare it before the rest of the code decides to run.

Comment: Interesting. Let me know when you resolve the issue.